# What is the feminine version of ‘macho’ or ‘machismo’?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A single word is preferable, but a phrase will suffice.

I found this reference at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/macho).

It suggests 'swagger' but I can't relate this to the Latin for 'feminine'.

I am hesistant in suggesting 'womacho' or more simply 'wocho', but I have done!

--(edit)--

This [ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114529/macho-for-women), ‘Macho for women’,  is similar but views *machismo* in its negative sense. A more positive view of *machismo* can be seen in films such as the *Die Hard* franchise. My view of female *wocho* is taking a seemingly impossible amount of time to apply make-up, amongst others, not necessarily aligned to a 'view of the Virgin Mary'.

*Butch* used to refer to lesbians, and I don't think *mannish* is polite. No male is actually offended by being called *macho*, and any word for *wocho* should reflect this.

Comment: I hate to say it, but *butch*, and perhaps *mannish* (which ought to make clear why I hate to say it).   There really ought to be something better, but the language perhaps hasn't caught up.  I hope someone has something better.

Comment: [This possible duplicate question of yours](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/114529/2085) was closed for being not constructive;  please show how yours is any different. You should also give example sentences where you would use this would-be word, the more the better. Please see our [guidelines on how to make a single word request](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I fear you may be facing a scenerios where there’s a built-in “cultural language lock” against such a form, just like there is with finding [a male counterpart to a tomboy](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/140942/2085).

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - you want "swagger" about being well put together in a feminine sense?  Like a *diva*? Or a *primadonna*?  Any form involving "macho" would be misleading in that sense, and in this day and age, insulting to (I'd like to hope) most women.

Comment: @stevesliva; that's a different q, a male diva is a superstar

Comment: Why do you all assume that 'macho' is necessarly a pejorative epithet?

Comment: The dictionary doesn't suggest "swagger" as a feminine alternative for "macho", it merely lists instances of "macho" found on the web. It is the linked website, not the dictionary, which uses this term but *linked* to "macho". [**Feminine Version of Macho Swagger**](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2013/03/29/five-girl-power-books-exactly-like-sheryl-sandberg-s-lean-in.html?source=dictionary) *“My pregnancy was not easy ... One day, after a rough morning spent staring at the bottom of the toilet, I had to rush to make an important client meeting.”*

Comment: The feminine of _macho_ is of course [_Macha_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macha). ;-)

Comment: You need to edit and clarify. The question still remains valid, even if you delete the reference to "swagger"

Comment: Maybe we need to redefine bitch.  Seriously.  I've sometimes called myself a bitch when I wanted to get across the message "Don't tread on me."

Comment: @ab2; i see no reason to redefine bitch - its current definition is fine

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry Ah, but would you call a woman a bitch to praise her for being strong and independent, with a  "don't tread on me" attitude that she can enforce?  And would you use the term in a way that made no sniggering judgment about her sexual habits?  That's what I meant about redefining, or rather extending, the definition of, bitch   This, I think, is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ab2; interesting...

Comment: macho appears to be male showing off, whether ritual or improvised, so i guess i'm looking the the phrase, preferably derived from Latin, for female showing off.

Answer (score 4):

**[marianismo:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marianismo)** a strong or exaggerated sense of traditional femininity

> [Marianismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianismo) is an aspect of the female gender role in the machismo of
>   Hispanic American folk culture. It is the veneration for feminine
>   virtues like purity and moral strength.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asks for an equivalent of "machismo," a noun, so here's a noun that might work (though it could also be used as an adjective):

**girl power**

> Power exercised by girls; spec. a self-reliant attitude among girls and young women manifested in ambition, assertiveness, and individualism. Although also used more widely (esp. as a slogan), the term has been particularly and repeatedly associated with popular music; most notably in the early 1990s with the briefly prominent ‘riot girl’ movement in the United States (cf. RIOT GIRL n.); then, in the late 1990s, with the British all-female group The Spice Girls.[13]

OED (2001), cited in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_power)

Though it doesn't have the connotations of *domineering* implicit in "macho" and "machismo," **girl power** carries their notion of *assertiveness*, and adds that of *empowerment* (which the masculine terms could never imply in the first place, with men of course throughout history having been ushered along by a congenital position of social advantage and privilege), associated as it is with contemporary [feminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-wave_feminism#History).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this covers what you seek: ***[Superwoman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superwoman)***.

> 1. a woman of extraordinary or superhuman powers.
> 2. a woman who copes successfully with the simultaneous demands of a career, marriage, and motherhood.

Reference:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superwoman

Comment: it's a noun not an adjective...

Comment: Well, Beyond what is possible for a woman is definitely less powerful.

Comment: clarification??

Comment: An adjective version of superwoman, that is.

Comment: Superwoman is an anglicism. I wouldn't count it as the feminine version of a Spanish masculine word.

Answer (score 0):

Machista, is what they call women like me, in Spanish.  It's for women who have a strong sense of self and don't buy into the machismo roles of males.  Although, I'm very girly and love dressing up and putting on makeup, it's used as an insult, to indicate I don't know my place, or role as a woman - usually by insecure men who don't understand that my place is wherever I want to be, even though I love being a woman.

Comment: ELU likes answers with references and explanations--about words and grammar and so forth, not self-descriptions.  Please edit your answer or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Hoyden
hoy·den
ˈhoidn/
noundated
a boisterous girl.

but she does say that Lydia has “high animal spirits”, which closely matches